# Disable linting for a specific file in VsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, linter

I have a file, "GeneratedCode" that at times is .ts .py or .c

I want to programmatically disable linting in VsCode whenever I view it.

Comment: do you still want syntax highlighting and language mode detection? Or do you not care?

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
"python.linting.ignorePatterns": [
    ".vscode/*.py",
    "**{filename or pattern}**",
    "**/site-packages/**/*.py"
]
```

Comment: but this is only for Python? what about Typescript and other

Comment: Well, you can do them in the same way